# How serious was my sister's Schengen overstay?

Tags: germany, overstaying, fines

My sister overstayed in Europe by just five days. She misread the expiring date of the visa. When she was exiting through Germany, the border service made her pay a fine of €110. Does this mean she is banned the Schengen area?

Answer (score 14):

Probably not.

It is possible for a member state to impose a Schengen-wide entry ban which will be be registered in the common Schengen Information System. But this requires that the subject of the ban is specifically *informed in writing* about the ban. Hopefully your sister has held on to all the paperwork she was given during the process.

Even if there is no formal ban, however, she should assume that the consular officers who examine future visa applications will know about the overstay; she will face a harder than normal task of convincing them that she intends to leave the Schengen area within the period stipulated by her visa.

The Schengen visa application form does not explicitly ask applicants to declare previous overstays -- but it will nevertheless be prudent to proactively provide an explanation as supporting material in a future visa application.

Comment: +1 but note that there is no indication in the question that the person had or needs a visa.

Comment: @Relaxed: How could she "misread the expiring date of the visa" otherwise? It sounds unlikely that the OP is confusing an entry stamp for a visa, since there is no expiry date to misread on those.

Comment: Must have missed that.

Comment: Her Visa was saying from From 24may to 24 June then underneath they was a part written duration 15 so she stupidly presumed that the visa was for 30 days but overlooked the 15 part . So she entered Shenley on the 2nd then left on 22nd two days b4 the 24th . she only realised that she overstayed when she was now at frankfurt airport that's when the immigration officer told her to pay a fine and allowed her to board a flight

Comment: @sasha: Usually the visa would only be issued with a length-of-stay of 15 days if the trip she documented in her visa application could fit within that. For a subsequent application she'll need to provide a coherent explanation not only of misreading the visa but also _how her plans changed_ from the thing the visa was issued for to what she actually did.